# IQueryProvider Execute IEnumerable to EnumerableQuery

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects, iqueryable

I have created a simple IQueryable:

```
var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(i => new TestDto()
{
       Id = i,
}).AsQueryable();
```

TestDto:

```
public class TestDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

While trying to execute the following line:

```
var test = data.Provider.Execute(data.Expression);
```

I get an exception stating:

```
Expression of type 
„System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Ilc.Tests.QueryAdapter.TestDto]” 
cannot be used for return type 
„System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[Ilc.Tests.QueryAdapter.TestDto]”.
```

I can't understand why I get this exception. 
What's more strange is that in debug view in Visual Studio (breakpoint) IQueryable `data` enumerates just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var test = data.Provider.Execute<IEnumerable<TestDto>>(data.Expression);
```